# Checked change event doesn't fire when disabled and unchecked through code in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

```
I just disable a checkbox and then Uncheck it through code. 
Checked change event is not triggered on changing the checked state.
```

But after this method is executed, again the checked state is set. This time event is triggeered.

Is there any reason for this?
Or Am I missing anything?

```
        private void updateUFOption()
        {
            bool dTrained = this.Test.Trained(0);

            // Disabled first
            checkBoxUseDie.Enabled = dTrained;

            if (!dTrained)
            {
                // Unchecked then
                checkBoxUseDie.Checked = false;
                Logger.LogInfo( CheckboxUseDie is Unchecked since not trained");
            }
        }
```

Comment: of course the event is not triggered if its disabled. thats the whole point if disabling. you dont want any events triggering

Comment: But now i reversed it to uncheck first and then disable. Still the event isn't triggered :(

Comment: Well, its working for me. What event exactly is not working for you?

Comment: checked changed event